# opacity acting weird (css)

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm having some problems with getting the right opacities for .div1. I can only make it a lower opacity than the .container or the same but I want it to be higher I want to get it to 1 instead of 0.92. Can anybody help me figure out how to get it .div1 to opacity lvl 1?

html:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="div1">sth1</div>  
    <div class="div2">sth2</div>  
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:black; 
    opacity: 0.92;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width:  100%;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: if its container is .92 , the child div's 1 opacity = .92 so reverse how youre doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opacity values are not inherited. Rather, they stack. So if you make `.container` have opacity 0.92, and don't change any other opacities, the CSS [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) of the child elements `div1` and `div2` will be 1 by default. Yet those child elements will look like they have 0.92 opacity, visually, because they're inside `container`. If you change `div1`'s `opacity` property to 0.5, then its visual opacity will be 0.92 * 0.5 = 0.46.

Thus, you can't have a child element be more opaque than its parent. A child element will always look at least as transparent as its parent.

To solve this, you could try to move the child element out of the parent. You could use absolute positioning to position it over the parent so it looks like it is inside. Alternatively, if the only reason you want opacity is to make the parent's background color transparent, you could specify a transparent color using [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29):

```css
.container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92); /* transparent black */
}
```